# Why do Declan & Carter Preston rush to Isabella's house when they find an FBI access code?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-jackal

In *The Jackal (1997)*, after Declan finds an **FBI Access code** by reading this book.

[image]

He and his partner, Carter Preston, hurriedly rushed to Isabella's house, where they found Witherspoon dead and Major Valentina Koslova mortally wounded by The Jackal.

How did the FBI Access codes lead them there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FBI Access Code allows The Jackal to access the Field Report given by Timothy Witherspoon in which he reveals the address of Isabella.

Preston contacts the FBI Data Center to hear the same information.

> WITHERSPOON'S VOICE:
>   Field report November Alpha filed 0900 hours... To perform interview of subject Isabella Zancona **at the following address**...